# "Fairly/Quite": stresses for "not exactly small" and "almost huge."

Tags: adverbs, ambiguity, stress

> When spoken, the meaning can vary with the tone of voice and stress:
> *He was **fairly/quite** bi*g can mean anything from "not exactly small" to "almost huge".
>
> https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quite#Usage_notes

What different phonological stresses is it referring to?

Is it the same situation as Wiktionary states for **pretty** ?

> [When particularly stressed, the adverb **pretty** serves almost to
> diminish the adjective or adverb that it modifies.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pretty#Usage_notes)

Comment: Vocal stress. How much emphasis is put on a word (and, as the author says, its tone.)

Comment: The 'almost huge' sense is achieved by using the raised-eyebrows equivalent of scare quotes. I'd say the whole expression is stressed here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth _raised-eyebrows_? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/raise_eyebrows

Comment: In answering another question about ["negative" dictionary definitions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/550759/do-dictionaries-make-negative-claims), I pointed out that one definition of *mediocre* as "not very good" has at least two meanings depending on the stress, only one of which IMO works for *mediocre.*

Comment: The past participle used as a premodifier (and thus requiring a hyphen) meaning 'having one's eyebrows raised [to convey emphasis]'.